# Откуда суффикс -л у существительных: "страшило", "чернила", "пряло" и т.п

Tags: этимология, морфология

В русском языке есть ряд существительных, образованных от глаголов, с суффиксом -л.

Какова причина использования этого суффикса? Ведь в современном русском языке это суффикс глагола прошедшего времени.

Comment: see also [Q: Существительное “забывало"](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8795/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE/8798#8798)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Суффикс **-л-о** происходит от праславянского суффикса **-dl-ŏ*, который служил для образования названий орудий. Происходит от [праиндоевропейского суффикса **-dʰl-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Slavic/-dlo), который соединялся с тематическим **ŏ* и образовывал имена среднего рода. В речи южных и восточных славян (в т. ч. в русском) в результате упрощения **-dl-* > [л], в западнославянских языках (в польском, чешском и др.) этот суффикс сохранил форму *-dl-o*: праслав. **my-dl-o* (от **my-ti*) >  полсьск. *mydło*, чешск. *mýdlo*, русск. *мыло*; праслав. **gьr-dl-o*  >  полсьск. *gardło*, чешск. *hrdlo*, русск. *горло*; праслав. **kri-dl-o-n* (от корня **kri-* «лететь») >  полсьск. *skrzydło*, чешск. *křídlo*, старослав. *крило*, русск. *крыло* (в последнем звук [ы], вероятно, под влиянием «крыть»); праслав. **zьrka-dl-o* >  полсьск. *zwierciadło*, чешск. *zrcadlo*, старослав. *зрьцало*, русск. *зеркало*.

Сходство этого суффикса с современным руским суффиксом прошедшего времени **-л-** является просто совпадением, никакой связи между ними нет.

Comment: Ну _пряло_, _горнило_ и т.п. положим, что так и есть. А _чернило_ - это тоже инструмент такой?

Comment: @user4419802 — Конечно. Мылом моют, прялом прядут, страшилом страшат, чернилом чернят. Вы что, не верите, что это другой суффикс, не современный суффикс прошедшего времени -л-? Лучшее доказательство моей правоты – это то, что суффикс прош. вр. -л- такой же во всех славянских языках, а этому суффиксу орудия в зап. славянских языках соответствует -dl-. Это разные суффиксы, совпавшие только в южных и восточных славянских языках.

Comment: В ПИЕ не обязательно суффикс был -dhl-om/tl-om, мог быть и просто -l-om

Comment: @Anixx — Если бы мы говорили о ПИЕ, то ваш комментарий как-то относился бы к обсуждаемому вопросу, сейчас же речь идёт о русском, и я в своём ответе детально объяснил, что данный современный русский суффикс -л- происходит именно от ПИЕ *-dʰl-om, а не от какого-либо другого его варианта.

Comment: ПИЕ -dhl-om проискодит от -tl-om происходит от -tr-om (то есть, от -ter-).

Comment: Класс) Это все объясняет.

Comment: Вау! А какой же тогда корень в словах _быдло_ и _повидло_?

Comment: @user244413 Быть и вить. В русском тоже есть существительные с этими корнями, например - быт и виток.

Comment: @user244413 — Оба эти слова заимствованы из польского, и да, их корни _быть_ и _вить_.